# Cordova not add platform [Ubuntu 14]

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu

I want develop mobile app with Cordova.

I installed Cordova and Android SDK but I have a problem.

I created new project but I didn't add android platform at this project.

```
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
```

I edited `.bashrc` and `.profile` files but my problem is go over.

Comment: Post the output of the following command, echo $ANDROID_HOME. Also post your  relevant .bashrc edits that you made for the Android SDK.

Comment: or just google: https://www.google.com/search?q=Error%3A+ANDROID_HOME+is+not+set+and+%22android%22+command+not+in+your+PATH&oq=Error%3A+ANDROID_HOME+is+not+set+and+%22android%22+command+not+in+your+PATH&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I checked ANDROID_HOME path. I have but My problem is go over.

Comment: I tried google's searchs.Thank you.